# How to get the total active users count in a particular page using angular 7

Tags: signalr, angular7

Is there any option to get the total active users count in a particular page using angular 7.

Thanks
Dileep

Comment: Please give us more details. For example there are trivial possibilities like Google Analytics, or custom logging, monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer yes. But how it depends how is your implementation. If you have only one instance or use `Azure SignalR` you just add a counter in the `OnConnectedAsync` method. If you have various instances, and if they communicate with for example `Redis Backplane` you can't just create a counter, you need to share state between the instances.